# Why $\int_{\mathcal I_+^+} \varepsilon*F=0$ for any $\varepsilon$ when there are no massive charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, differential-geometry, maxwell-equations, asymptotics

My problem is really simple. I was reading the [Strominger lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448) where he defines the future charges $Q_\varepsilon^+$, and he does something that I don't understand. He says on the equation $(2.5.4)$ that without massive charges the following affirmation is true:

$$
I=\int_{\mathcal I_+^+}
\varepsilon*F=0
$$

Where $F$ is the *Electromagnetic Tensor*, $\,\mathcal I^+$ is the *Future Null Infinity*, $\,\mathcal I^+_-$ is its past and $\,\mathcal I^+_+$ is its future. And the only condition for $\varepsilon$ is that it obeys $\varepsilon\big|_{\mathcal I^+_-}=\varepsilon\big|_{\mathcal I^-_+}$

The reason for this affirmation according to the book is that the electric field will vanish at $\mathcal I^+_+$. I don't know why these affirmations are true.

---

**My attempts:**

*Attempt 1:* If there is no charges, according to Maxwell equations:

$$
d*F=0\implies *F=d\omega
$$

Where $\omega$ is a $1$-form. Then the integral is:

$$
I=\int_{\mathcal I_+^+}
\varepsilon \,d\omega
$$

Using $d(\alpha\wedge\beta)=d\alpha\wedge\beta+(-1)^p\alpha\wedge d\beta$ where $\alpha$ is a $p$-form:

$$
I=\int_{\mathcal I_+^+}
\Big[
d(\varepsilon\omega)
+\omega\wedge d\varepsilon
\Big]
$$

And I suppose I could do something with the [generalized Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) or something like that. But I really have no clue.

*Attempt 2:* I kind of have an intuition, maybe it is wrong, $\mathcal I^+_+$ is like a $2$-manifold (on spacetime) of size going to zero, so all the integrals of the form $\int_{I^+_+}$ will be zero.

***Any help or advice would be awesome.***

---

**References:**

[Lectures on the Infrared Structure of Gravity and Gauge Theory - Andrew Strominger](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05448)

[Lectures on Youtube](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwLjkVy3evOazQ3FoRH-Sz8Eoxx2oriXL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure but here is my guess. Somehow the fact that the particle is massless must come into play. From equation 2.3.2

$$
F_{rt}\rvert_{\mathcal{I}^+} = \frac{e^2}{4 \pi r^2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{Q_k}{\gamma_k^2 (1 - \hat x \cdot \vec{\beta}_k )^2}.
$$
When computing $\star F$ over an $S^2$ integral at $\mathcal{I}^+_+$, only the $\phi$ and $\theta$ components of $\star F$ come into play. This is the same as the $r$ and $t$ components of $F$. Note that $F_{rt}$ above goes as $1/r^2$ while our spherical integral will go as $r^2$, so a priori we will have a $\mathcal{O}(1)$ left over. So something about this expression must go to zero if the particles are massless. I think it is $\gamma_k$ of the particles. If $|\beta_k| = 1$ then $\gamma_k \to \infty$ and $F_{rt} \to 0$.  (However, I think you also have to check that $(1 - \hat x \cdot \vec{\beta}_k)^2$ won't somehow mess this up. Also, would this mean that the expression is zero on the whole $\mathcal{I}^+$, save for maybe a discrete set of $\hat x$?)

Also, if you continually struggle to make sense of the book, I think some of the original papers go into more detail and may be a bit clearer on some technical points. A quick arxiv search reveals the following promising looking results.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02906

https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2763

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3814

https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3789

Comment: You were right. The integral was (if I made the integral right): $\int_{\mathcal I_+^+}\varepsilon*F=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\gamma^2_k}\cdot\frac{Q_ke^2}{4\pi}\int  \varepsilon\frac{\sin\theta \,d\theta \,d\phi}{(1-\vec\beta\cdot\hat r)^2}$ and when there are only massless charges $\gamma_k\to\infty$ and therefore $\int_{\mathcal I_+^+}\varepsilon*F=0$. I had to learn things that apparently I didn't know. Today I'm less noob than yesterday, so thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Typo: I had a wrong sign on $\int_{\mathcal I^+_+} \varepsilon * F$, I mean it must be: $\int_{\mathcal I^+_+} \varepsilon * F=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{\gamma_k^2}\cdot\frac{Q_k e^2}{4\pi}\int \varepsilon \frac{\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi}{(1-\vec\beta\cdot\hat r)^2}$